# Rails Pages are not rendering correctly, getting flashes in-between loads

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I have a rails 4 app that I am working on and have it pushed to heroku.  When I render new views I get random flashes in between page loads, including the top bar which is in my application.html so I don't think it should be have long load time.  I think this is due to the speed that the page is rendering but I am not sure.  I am using foundation Zurb so I have disabled turbo-links.  Is there any way that I can fix this/what could be causing this to happen?  Below is the application HTML, and the link to my app.

http://kaizano.herokuapp.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Kaizano" %>
    </title>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-icons.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body class="page-body">
    <nav class='top-bar' data-topbar>
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1 class="title-font"><%= link_to "Kaizano", root_path %></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="fixed">
      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Join a Presentation", events_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Me", user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>       
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">More</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><%= link_to "How it Works", how_it_works_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "About", learn_mores_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Contact Us",new_contact_form_path %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Join a Presentation", events_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", learn_mores_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up",new_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign In",new_user_session_path %></li>      
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">More</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><%= link_to "How it Works",how_it_works_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Contact Us",new_contact_form_path %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
    <%= yield %>
 o</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving your javascript include tag to the bottom of the body.
And follow the advise from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkaizano.herokuapp.com%2F&tab=desktop or `yslow`